# ORA-12541: TNS: no listener in SSIS

Tags: oracle11g, ssis, oracleclient

We have oracle oledb connections in SSIS packages that are working well on windows server 2008.

We moved them to windows server 2012 and installed the needed softwares. We installed oracle client (oraoledb driver), moved **tnsnames.ora, ldap.ora and sqlnet.ora** to `%Oracle_Home%\Network\admin` path, add `%Oracle_Home%` and `%Oracle_Home%\bin` to path variable.

But on server 2012 oracle connections are giving this error **ORA-12541: TNS: no listener**. Where as on server 2008 same oracle connections are working fine.

Looked so much across internet but found these solutions:

1. Check tnsnames.ora
2. Check listener is running
3. Check path variable contain oracle home, oracle_home\bin

I don't see a problem with tnsnames.ora because same file is present on both window servers. Correct path variables are also set. Listener is also running (since SSIS on server 2008 is connecting). And I am able to ping oracle db server from both machines.

Can anyone suggest anything that we may try.

Comment: Can you connect from this new server to Oracle using SQLPLUS.EXE? If not you may need to open a port

Comment: I just tried. There also getting TNS: No listener error. What port are you referring to here?

Comment: Then it's not a SSIS issue. When you connect to Oracle you connect over a network port. Usually 1521 but it can be different. I'm not sure if the TNS Listener error actually indicates that. To test, first work out what port Oracle is running on, then run `TELNET <oraclehost> <port>` in a command prompt

Comment: Telnet establishes a connection from windows server 2008 but connection fails when i try from windows server 2012. I think this must be the root cause. I'll check once i get the connectivity between these two. Thanks for pointing to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a formal answer in here.

Basic troubleshooting steps with SSIS:

1. Use the database native tools to check connectivity

   - In this case for Oracle that is `SQLPLUS.EXE`
   - If you have an issue with native tools then it isn't an SSIS issue
2. Check that you can resolve the host by using `PING <hostname>`.

   - If that doesn't work try `PING <ip address>`
3. If ping works, check the port with `TELNET <host> <port>`

   - If that doesn't work, either the service is not listening or you need to get your network guys to open the port

This goes for *any* network service

i.e.

- SQL Server (default port 1433)
- a web server (default port 80 for unencrypted comms)